# BigQuery: output ISO string for a timestamp field?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with a TIMESTAMP field.

I have read through [the available functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#functions), but I can't find a way to output the ISO string of the timestamp field.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you should check bigquery standard sql - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators

Comment: Thanks! I did see that, but if I do `TIMESTAMP(mycol) as mycol` I still don't seem to get an ISO string back.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the exact format? ISO doesn't specify just a single date-time format, so your question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your field is of the TIMESTAMP type, the following will produce
ISO 8601/ISO 3339 compliant representation:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%X%Ez", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

This returns a value such as `2017-09-13T22:44:28+00:00`.

For more information, see the [`FORMAT_TIMESTAMP` documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format_timestamp).